# Regex for yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, regex

So this is my input (valid date-time): `2019-03-14 18:00:00`

I want to match `2019-03-14`

This is my regex: `\d{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*`

But it gives me 3 matches. `2019-03-14`, `03`, `4`

What should I change to just match: `2019-03-14` ?

Comment: You might as well parse the whole date and format it again.

Comment: It gives only 1 match.

Comment: It should give you a single match with two groups ; what's your js code?

Comment: Do you need to validate input string - or you assume that your string with data is valid?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski That the data is valid. A-312 already helped. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can use a non-capturing group (the parentheses will not remember the match) with `?:`

```
\d{4}-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*
```

```js
var regex = /\d{4}-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*/;

console.log("2019-03-14 18:00:00".match(regex));
```

- [Read more on Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: `(?:something)`  is a *non-capturing* group, not "unmatching group".

Comment: capturing* groups, and the exact same content will still be matched, it's just that parts of it won't be captured in specific groups

Comment: @A-312 Thanks. Had no idea such thing as groups existed as my regex worked fine in an online regex editor.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
let d= "2019-03-14 18:00:00".split(' ')[0];

let r= "2019-03-14 18:00:00".match(/[^ ]*/)[0];

console.log('split: ', d);
console.log('regexp:', r);
```

Comment: I think OP still needs the date verification provided by their own regex.

Comment: @Seblor OP don't mention about date validation in question - the date validation can be separate question

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking things, but OP did not mention the verification thing because it was out of scope. Their issue being the unnecessary capturing groups.

Comment: He doesn't mention it because it's already working fine. Your code may solve one problem, but it brings a huge regression if validation is indeed needed (which must be the case, otherwise why would he bother making sure he doesn't extract month 24 or day 65 with his regex).

Comment: @Aaron The data is already valid from the server. For example month 24 or day 65 will never be in the string. I am pretty new to regex so I dont know exactly whats right. My issue in this case was capturing groups as Seblor mentioned.

Comment: @Diar If you are already sure the data is valid, you do not need to use a big and "slow" regex like you do in your question. Kamil's is way better performance-wise.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Thanks. Works perfectly.